# NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined

Tags: python

I have written a small piece of code in Python, I was trying to run the code from the command line as follows

> python -c MyClass.py

The contents of MyClass.py are as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import logging;

class MyClass():
    data = None
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def __init__(self, data):
    self.data   = data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = MyClass("Data")
    a.logger.info("This is message")
```

The above code fails with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined
```

Mind you, when I ran this from the python tool, IDLE, I saw no issues and the code ran as expected, I am confused as to what I am missing. Also, I saw several variants of this question, but the problem I am facing is specific to me,so , please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code fails is that you are using wrong command line option:

> ```
>     -c command
>           Specify the command to execute (see next section).
>           This terminates the option list (following options
>           are passed as arguments to the command).
> ```

So, what you give after `-c` is evaluated as a statement, like `python -c "print('Hello!')"`. So, with `-c MyClass.py` you are literally trying to access an attribute named `py` from an object named `MyClass`, which is likely not what you are trying to do.

To execute source code from file `MyClass.py`, you should omit `-c`: `python MyClass.py`.

However, your code won't work either because of two reasons:
1. You are using non-configured logger instance
2. Your logging level is way too low to notice the error.

For example, replace `logger.info` with `logger.warning` — you will immediately get `No handlers could be found for logger "__main__"` error. Searching reference for this message leads us to *[15.6.1.6. Configuring Logging for a Library](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library)* section. Reason is that you are trying to access the logger that is not configured — so it has no idea what to do next with generated messages.

To address this, in your main project file you can configure your logger as suggested in section *[15.6.1.5. Configuring Logging](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html#configuring-logging)*, using either your own handler, or reusing some library-provided shortcuts for common tasks, as per section *[15.6.3. Useful Handlers](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html#module-logging.handlers)*.

Comment: When ran as "python MyClass.py" , I dont see any output printed to the console, hence I was forced to use ` python -c MyClass.py`

Comment: That's because you haven't configured your `logging` instance. Please take a look at _[15.6.1.5. Configuring Logging](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html#configuring-logging)_ and _[15.6.3. Useful Handlers](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html#module-logging.handlers)_

Comment: Thank you !, that worked for me, seems like there are more than one mistake.

Comment: @AparnaChaganti, if one of solutions worked for you, you are welcome to mark relevant answer as an accepted by ticking the check mark.

Answer (score 2):

The `-c` flag is to run the passed string as Python code. `python -c MyClass.py` is equivalent to opening a fresh interpreter and entering `MyClass.py`. When you do that, `MyClass` isn't defined, so it fails. To run a script from your system's terminal, simply use `python MyClass.py`.

Comment: When ran as "python MyClass.py" , I dont see any output printed to the console, hence I was forced to use ` python -c MyClass.py`.

Comment: @AparnaChaganti - Well, you didn't `print()` anything, and I don't think `logging.getLogging().info()` sends anything to the standard output automatically, so it stands to reason that you wouldn't see any output. I'm curious as to why you thought that the `-c` option would be a solution at all, much less why you were "forced" to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`python -c "import MyClass"` will work, but why not run it with a command `python MyClass.py`?

> When ran as "python MyClass.py" , I dont see any output printed to the console, hence I was forced to use `python -c MyClass.py`.

It work well, because of logging level setting,you can not see log message
.you can set log level or use high level such as logger.error("msg").

Anyway, `a.logger.error("This is message")` will get `No handlers could be found for logger "__main__"`.It's clear that there is no handlers for logger "**main**",you need set it or using "root" logger by `logging.info("message")`

Good luck!